# Can you sneak an "insert" into a "select" statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Is it possible to sneak an "insert" statement (or anything else that changes the database) into a MySQL "select" statement?

I ask because I'm concerned I've found an injection vulnerability, but it's safeguarded from obvious mayhem like `'; drop database; --` by virtue of only being able to run a single statement at a time, no matter how many statements the query has been corrupted to contain.  But if the back end is executing something like `select bar from foo where param = '$improperly_escaped_input'`, is there something I can input that will compromise my database?

The vulnerability needs to be corrected, regardless.  But if I can show an example of how it can be exploited to screw with the data, fixing it goes way up in the priority queue.

Comment: How do you avoid running more than one statement at a time?

Comment: It could be a vulnerability regardless of whether data can be modified. If people can alter the query to access data other than their own or modify a permission query to always return true, you'll still be in trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modification of data is only one aspect of a Sql Injection vulnerability.  Even with just read permissions, an attacker can elevate their privileges, or use a [Blind Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Blind_SQL_injection) attack to scrape every last bit of data out of your database.

I can't think of a way off the top of my head that data would be modified inside a select statement... but, [are you sure that you're only able to run a single command at a time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)?

Regardless, the other attack vectors should be enough of a threat to raise the priority on the issue.

EDIT: [Data modification is allowed in MySql sub-queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html):

> MySQL permits a subquery to refer to a stored function that has
>   data-modifying side effects such as inserting rows into a table. For
>   example, if f() inserts rows, the following query can modify data:
>
> `SELECT ... WHERE x IN (SELECT f() ...);`
>
> This behavior is nonstandard
>   (not permitted by the SQL standard). In MySQL, it can produce
>   indeterminate results because f() might be executed a different number
>   of times for different executions of a given query depending on how
>   the optimizer chooses to handle it.

Comment: The documentation for PHP's mysql_query says it only allows one query (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and my own experimentation suggests that using a semicolon to create a second statement doesn't work.  But you're right, the potential for data scraping is enough for me to argue quite strongly for dealing with this sooner rather than later.

Comment: @BlairHippo Hmmm... the link in my answer to the MySql doc conflicts with the PHP doc, and provides an example of `mysql_query` being used to execute multiple statements... but I have no proof one way or the other...

Comment: [CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html) - `Enable multiple-statement support`. Disabled by default.